# In ggplot2, how to choose which geom appears in legend?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Some geom obscure the key to other geoms in the legend (notably, boxplot)

How can I choose which geom appears in the legend?

Eg.:

```
qplot(data=CO2,
      x=Type,
      y=uptake,
      colour=Plant,
      shape=Treatment)+
        geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

Switching the order of the geoms helps

```
qplot(data=CO2,
      x=Type,
      y=uptake,
      colour=Plant,
      shape=Treatment,
      geom="boxplot")+
        geom_point()
```

[image]

But I would like the legend found with:

```
qplot(data=CO2,
      x=Type,
      y=uptake,
      colour=Plant,
      shape=Treatment)
```

[image]

Do I need to extract the legend of one plot and paste it to the other using something like gridExtra?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can suppress the legend for the boxplot by adding `show_guide=FALSE` to the `geom_boxplot()` call. You still get the legend from the points.

```
qplot(data=CO2,
      x=Type,
      y=uptake,
      colour=Plant,
      shape=Treatment)+
        geom_boxplot(show_guide=FALSE)
```

[image]

If you were not already plotting points (that is, just had boxplot, but wanted the legend to be shown with points symbol rather than the boxplot symbol), that is harder, though I think possible.